# Problema al cargar componente hijo con angular material 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, material-design, angular2-template

Estoy intentando cargar un componente hijo el cual solo seria la una toolbar pero me sale error con angular material pero si cargo el toolbar desde mi appcomponent no hay problema pero cuando lo inteto separar me sale esto  [image: Este es el error]
este es mi app.component

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular2-material/card';
import {BarComponent} from './bar.component'
import { MD_BUTTON_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular2-material/button';
import {MdIcon, MdIconRegistry} from '@angular2-material/icon';
import { MdToolbar } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [MD_CARD_DIRECTIVES,BarComponent,MD_BUTTON_DIRECTIVES, MdIcon, MdToolbar],
    providers: [MdIconRegistry]

})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

y este es mi barcomponent

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MD_BUTTON_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular2-material/button';
import {MdIcon, MdIconRegistry} from '@angular2-material/icon';
import { MdToolbar } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';
@Component({
    selector: '<bar></bar>',
    templateUrl: 'bar.component.html',
    directives: [MD_BUTTON_DIRECTIVES, MdIcon, MdToolbar],
    providers: [MdIconRegistry]
})
export class BarComponent  {

    constructor() { }

}
```

y sus html correspondientes

```
    <bar></bar>
<md-card>
   <md-card-subtitle>Subtitle first</md-card-subtitle>
   <md-card-title>Card with title</md-card-title>   
   <md-card-content>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad</p>
   </md-card-content>
   <md-card-actions>
        <button md-button>LIKE</button>
        <button md-button>SHARE</button>
   </md-card-actions>
</md-card>
```

bar.component.html

```
    <md-toolbar>
  Menu
</md-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, revise el selector de su componente, creo que ese “selector: '/bar>'" es incorrecto. Adicionalmente, a su componente agréguele la propiedad modulo en la configuración de su componente. Debería tener algo como esto:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'bar',
    templateUrl: 'bar.component.html',
    directives: [MD_BUTTON_DIRECTIVES, MdIcon, MdToolbar],
    providers: [MdIconRegistry]
})
```

La propiedad moduleId es importante, ya que en combinación CommonJS permiten la carga de los templates usando las rutas relativas. La información detallada la encuentra en la [documentación oficial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html)